# Inserir dados apartir de VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho duas planilhas no qual uma delas é um como se fosse um formulário e irá inserir os dados na outra planilha.

A minha questão é que ele insere mas sempre na mesma linha... como faço para ir adicionando na linha seguinte?

Neste caso criei a função linha, mas tentei colocar Cells(linha, 3) pois onde quero adicionar a tabela está na terceira coluna (C) e na linha 4 ou seja C4...

```
    'Verifica última linha preenchida
linha = Range("C4").End(xlDown).Row + 1

'Adicionar Data Receção
Sheets("Adicionar Registo").Select
Range("d4").Copy
Sheets("Matérias-primas am").Select
Range("C18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Adicionar Guia Remessa
Sheets("Adicionar Registo").Select
Range("L4").Copy
Sheets("Matérias-primas am").Select
Range("D18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 'Adicionar Fornecedor
Sheets("Adicionar Registo").Select
Range("P4").Copy
Sheets("Matérias-primas am").Select
Range("E18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que a tua função linha está a funcionar correctamente, ou seja, a ir buscar o valor da linha na folha correcta

deves substituir as linhas onde colas os valores

```
Range("C18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D18").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

por

```
Range("C" & linha).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("D" & linha).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
....
```

Comment: Augusto Vasques, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Neste caso só tive de adicionar o código para selecionar a folha correta e ficou a dar perfeitamente até ver :)